# Curious problemm on less/css property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm having a curious problem with Less (bootstrap), in the property border-botom-color (CSS side).

I have this example where the bottom line of the active tab (Section 1) appears:

[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rochasdv/7wrww/)

And I have this exemple where the bottom line of the active tab (Section 1) do not appears:

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rochasdv/9xbSu/)

The unique diference is on CSS, at line 5365, in the fisrt example is `border-bottom-color: transparent;`, and in second example is `border-bottom-color: #FFF;`

I would like know why "transparent" do not works but putting a color (like #FFF) it works?

Comment: Don't just post all of your code in a jsFiddle. It is meant to give a simplified example of your problem. Include only relevant code.

Comment: see my comment. hope it helping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `ul.nav-tabs` tag (parent of `a` tag) have colored border, the long grey horizontal border (see [jsfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/rochasdv/7wrww/) line 5328). you need to set `a` border bottom color as white to override it's parent border, so it will be look transparent.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is because that line is being generated somewhere else. So when you put `border-bottom-color:transparent;` you are just seeing the other line right through it. But when you make it white, you are drawing a new white line over it.

[fiddle displaying issue](http://jsfiddle.net/bennett_an/M8gZK/)

Answer (score 1):

`transparent` just adds a completely transparent border over the top of the one defined by the `border` property hence the color is shown. `#fff` is shown over the top of the border and blocks out the other color hence white is shown. You could get around the problem by specifying a color for each border individually.